# F# Lazy and Exceptions

Tags: exception, f#, lazy-evaluation

Given this example:

```
let value = try (lazy raise(Exception())).Value with | _ -> false
```

Why is the exception not captured in the try block. Keep in mind that I raise the exception like this to prove the example. The point is that if I have a lazy code that throws and exception, it seems to be unable to capture in the try block. Do I have to be specific in my match of the exception or do I have to capture the exception inside the lazy expression itself?

Comment: seems like you changed your question and your example is not doing what you descripe anymore

Comment: I have not changed anything since I posted the question.

Comment: strange ... because this code will work just as expected (see all the answers)

Answer (score 0):

The following prints both the exception and the value which is false.

```
let value = 
    try 
        (lazy raise(System.Exception())).Value 
    with  
        | exn -> printfn "%A" exn
                 false
printfn "%A" value
```

Comment: What version of F# are you using? I copied your code exactly as it is and still raises the exception. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to rep your results. What are you seeing?

```
let value = 
    try 
        (lazy raise(Exception())).Value 
        true
    with
     | ex -> 
         printfn "got exception"; 
         false
```

Gives me

```
got exception

val value : bool = false
```

Edit:

Adding debugging image

[image]

Comment: I copied your code and ran it exactly as is. When I ran using the debugger the exception was thrown and not captured, but if I ran without the debugger everything when perfectly fine. Is this the expected behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: @StalinPimentel I'm not sure what you're doing but it does work just fine.  I've attached an image showing the debugger catching the exception

Comment: oh I see ... F# will show you the exceptions as thrown sometimes - just go on with F5 and you will see that the exception is captured ;) (I think this got changed in the later versions - but F# 2 in VS2010 hat this *problem*)

Comment: @CarstenKönig, it was exactly as you suggested. Hitting F5 again continued with the execution. I'm more used to C# so I thought that was the end. By the way, I'm using VS 2012 which I suppose comes with F# 3.0. I'll give it a try in VS 2013.

Comment: @StalinPimentel possible - I use VS2013 now and I did not see something like this for quite some time - but I used to give me the creeps when debuging Socket code with frequent disconnects ;)